# PHP Globally visible login

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I went through quite a few articles and couldnt find what I am looking for. I have previously tried using $GLOBALS but that doesnt work to well when querying mysql.

The problem I have here is that I want a username visible on the entire page and all the php files included after a username and password is confirmed on the login screen.

Example of what I mean (password hashing removed for simplification):

```
<?php
include('config.php');

global $logged;

$email = $_POST["email"];
$GLOBALS['email'] = $email;

$password = $_POST["password"];

$results = sqlQuery("SELECT upassword FROM usertable WHERE useremail='$email' LIMIT 1");

foreach ($results as $result)
{
    $cpassword = $result[0][0];
}

if($cpassword === $password)
{
    echo "Login succesful";
    $logged = 0;
    Redirect('index.php', false);
}
else
{
    $logged = 1;
    echo "Incorrect Username or Password";
}
?>
```

==============================

```
function sqlQuery($sql) {
global $db_conn;
// execute query    
$db_result = mysql_query($sql, $db_conn);
// if db_result is null then trigger error
if ($db_result === null) {
    trigger_error(mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error() . "\n");
    exit();
}
// prepare result array
$resultSet = Array();
// if resulted array isn't true and that is in case of select statement then open loop
// (insert / delete / update statement will return true on success) 
if ($db_result !== true) {
    // loop through fetched rows and prepare result set
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($db_result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        // first column of the fetched row $row[0] is used for array key
        // it could be more elements in one table cell
        $resultSet[$row[0]][] = $row;
    }
}
// return result set
return $resultSet;
}
```

==================

```
<?php
// include config with database definition
include('config.php');

// start transaction
sqlQuery('start transaction');

// delete all
sqlQuery('delete from sometable');

// accept parameters - p is array (suppress errors by adding "@" sign)
$arr = @$_REQUEST['p'];

// if input array exists (in all cases except deleting last element)
if (is_array($arr)) {
// open loop through each array element
foreach ($arr as $p) {
    // detach values from combined parameters
    // $tbl parameter is ignored because saving goes only from table 1
    list($sub_id, $row, $col) = explode('_', $p);
    // discard clone id part from the sub_id
    $sub_id = substr($sub_id, 0, 2);
    // insert to the database
    sqlQuery("insert into sometable (sub_id, tbl_row, tbl_col) values      ('$sub_id', $row, $col)");
}
}

// commit transaction (sqlCommit is function from config.php)
sqlCommit();

// redirection to the index.php
header('location: index.php');
?>
```

Now if i were to use the $GLOBALS['email'] seen in login name in the query:
        sqlQuery("insert into sometable (sub_id, tbl_row, tbl_col) values      ('$sub_id', $row, $col)"); this would fail, how can you do it?

Comment: Globals are per execution context. Why don't you use sessions?

Comment: Global variables are considered bad habit and I can confirm that from my experience, they are trouble makers.

Answer (score 2):

The comment explains what Globals are used for. Even though you should almost never use Globals.

Now, to your question. put `session_start()` at the top of your script. Right, after `<?php`

Then, modify this block of code.

```
if($cpassword === $password)
{
    echo "Login succesful";
    $logged = 0;
    Redirect('index.php', false);
    $_SESSION['user_email']= (isset($_POST['email'])) ? $_POST['email'] : false;
}
```

Now, everything you need is to echo the email, you can use `echo $_SESSION['user_email']` at any time and any place in your script. As long as the function `session_start()` is available to that page.

Your code and overall logic does miss some conventions and standards, so I suggest you read [PHP the right way](http://phptherightway.com). To learn some good stuff.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\bachelor\index.php on line 35 :( seems not to work I have added session_start(); in both the files.

Comment: @corpseRott check it now. Please don't add more than one `session_start()` in the same application.

Comment: Now I seem to get: Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\bachelor\index.php on line 32 - its the same line

Comment: @corpseRott That means you have not created `session_start()` I told you to write that BEFORE ANY piece of PHP code. Just after `<?php` if that file is included, then write it in the parent file

Comment: I did. session_start(); is at the very top of the page where the variable is set. I have also tried putting it on other pages to make sure, but that didnt work neither. Both added in one page or many, doesnt work.

Comment: Ok do `var_dump(function_exists('session_start'));` anywhere and tell me the result.

Comment: I think you may need to include the `session_start()` inside your `config.php` after the `<?php` syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SESSIONS` and store the username of whatever information you would like for the current `session` there.

For example once you start your session `$_SESSION['username']`.

On every page now you can `echo $_SESSION['username']`.